# Ruby on Rails - how to handle belongs_to multiple on create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I'm trying to create a Comment that belongs_to multiple Models but I'm not sure on what the best practice is to assign it to both.

```
class Comment < ApplicationRecord
    validates :message, :presence => true
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :discussion
end
```

When creating a Comment within a Discussion, I run into the error "Discussion must exist".

I'm using Devise so I am using current_user and building a Comment to align it with them, but I'm not sure on exactly how to point it to both. This seems to work, but seems very hacky.

```
def create
    @comment = current_user.comments.build(comment_params)
    @comment.discussion_id = params[:discussion_id]
    ...
end
```

What's the best practice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would add the `:discussion_id` to the `comment_params` method:

```
def create
  @comment = current_user.comments.build(comment_params)
  ...
end

private

def comment_params
  params.require(:comment)
        .permit(...)
        .merge(discussion_id: params.require(:discussion_id))
end
```

**Or** you could use `build` with a block:

```
def create
  @comment = current_user.comments.build(comment_params) { |comment| 
    comment.discussion_id = params[:discussion_id] 
  }
  # ...
end
```

Comment: I tried your answer with merge, but it gives me an error.  "undefined method `to_h' for "1":String Did you mean? to_r to_f to_i to_d to_c to_s"
for "params.require(:comment).permit(:message, :group_id).merge(params.require(:discussion_id))"

Comment: Awesome, I got that working. Now I'll just need to get it working on the Discussion Model as that's also a nested under another Model. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

No matter how you go about it, you do need to either set `discussion_id` or get it to be present in `comment_params`.

Does this look less hacky to you?

```
def create
    comment_params.merge(discussion_id: params[:discussion_id])
    @comment = current_user.comments.build(comment_params)
    ...
end
```

Answer (score 2):

You can pass additional params in the block

```
params = ActionController::Parameters.new({
  comment: {
    name: 'Francesco',
    body:  'Text'
  }
})

comment_params = params.require(:comment).permit(:name, :body)

def create
  @comment = current_user.comments.build(comment_params) do |comment|
    comment.discussion_id = params[:discussion_id]
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several things you need to keep in mind when you create an entity which is associated to more than one entity.

With respect to your question regarding to best practices. I would like to emphasise the usage of an interactor here:

```
# xx_controller.rb
def create
  success = CreateComment.call(params)
  if success
     ....
  else
     ....
  end
end


# ../../create_comment.rb
# pseudocode
class CreateComment
  def call(params)
    validate your params # check if nothing is missing, the discussion exists and you have a user
    build_and_save_your_comment
    return_your_result_object # return a tuple or a result or whatever you need in order to handle errors and success cases...
  end
end
```

With this approach you keep the readability within your controller and you can focus on what matters to the comment creation in a dedicated place.